# Checking whether a shell option is set with [ -o OPTION ], weird behavior when OPTION is on

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I am in the process of reading [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/Bash-Beginners-Guide.pdf) bash guide from the Linux Documentation Project.
On page 81 and 82 there's a short example script for testing whether an option is set:

```
if [ -o noclobber ]
    then
    echo "Your files are protected against accidental overwriting using redirection."
fi
```

I have run into some weird behavior when trying to negate the test. I am getting a return value of 0 for all options that are turned on for `[ -o OPTION ]` and `[ ! -o OPTION ]`. Here's an example:

```
$ set -o | grep errex
errexit         off
$ [ -o errexit ]; echo $?
1
$ [ ! -o errexit ]; echo $?
0
$ set -o | grep history
history         on
$ [ -o history ]; echo $?
0
$ [ ! -o history ]; echo $?
0
```

Comment: I don't see that -o does what you expect `man test | grep -A1 "\-o"`.

Comment: You do `set -o | grep errex`: note that that's not a reliable way to check an option. Pipes are executed in subshells, so `set -o` is executed in a subshell, and they don't necessarily inherit all of the parents shells options. E.g. (`zsh`): `setopt monitor; set -o | grep monitor` -> `monitor off`: _clearly wrong_, because `set -o` is executed in a subshell of where the option is set. (On the other hand: `(setopt monitor; set -o) | grep monitor` -> `monitor on`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[[ ! -o option ]]` instead. Parsing of expressions in `[[ ]]` is more predictable.

The result you're seeing with `[` is because there are two `-o` operators in bash's `test` builtin: unary `-o option` to check if an option is set, and binary `test1 -o test2` to check if either test is true (logical or).

You are passing `test` three arguments, `!`, `-o` and `history`. Let's see what [POSIX says about it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) how to parse three arguments:

```
3 arguments:
  - If $2 is a binary primary, perform the binary test of $1 and $3.
  - If $1 is '!', negate the two-argument test of $2 and $3.
  (...)
```

`-o`, is indeed a binary operator, so it performs the test of `$1` and `$3`, which become the "is non-empty" check (like in `[ ! ]` and `[ history ]`). The result is therefore true.

The second interpretation is what you expected, but it's not used since the first interpretation matched.

Comment: +1. `! [ -o option]` is also possible in the unlikely event that you have a shell which doesn't understand `[[`.

Comment: @rici `-o` for options is in itself bash specific, so that would be unlikely indeed.

Comment: Good point. It's still useful to know that ! is not just for inside brackets.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why the behavior when using [[ is working like expected?

Comment: @timgeb It's basically a bug or misfeature in `[` that has to remain in place for backwards compatibility. `[[` came decades later and didn't have to carry the same legacy baggage.

Comment: @thatotherguy alright, so [[ works as expected because it does not try the "first interpretation" for three arguments you provided?

Comment: @timgeb `[[` doesn't use binary `-o` at all, avoiding the problem. But it also uses a proper expression parser with well defined operator precedence, rather than taking shortcuts based on argument count.